# creating table rowspan php

Tags: php, tablerow

i need help with my code..how do i have output like in the image below where it will automatically insert rowspan ..my current code

```
$result = $cmsDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$cmsDB->prefix("departments")."");

echo "<br /><br /><table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
<tr>
<th>Bil</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Staff</th>
</tr>";

$count =1 ;

while($row = $cmsDB->fetchArray($result))
{
$deptid=$row['deptid']; 
$deptname=$row['deptname']; 
 
echo "<tr><td>".$count++."</td><td>".$deptname."</td><td>";
global $cmsDB;
  $result2 = $cmsDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$cmsDB->prefix("staff")." WHERE deptid=$deptid");
  
while($row = $cmsDB->fetchArray($result2))
{

$name=$row['name']; 
echo "".$name." <br />";

}

}


echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

[image: current output]

[image: Desired result]

current output and desired results

Comment: Why use `global $myDB;`? `$myDB` is already available in that scope.

Comment: oops it suppossed to be mycms db

Comment: Count the return prior to building the rows, then use it on the element creations. You also need to create more cells in the `while` loop.

Comment: My point still stands, why use `global $cmsDB;`? `$cmsDB` is already available in that scope.

Comment: Im a newbie...so is this unnecessary and can be remove ? Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Note: By design performing two queries for this just a bad idea. Still going with that. All you need to do is to perform the second query ahead of creating the  block. Record the counts of the result Data and use that as rowSpan. Quite Simple.

```
global $myDB;
$result2 = $myDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$myDB->prefix("staff")." WHERE deptid=$deptid");

$rowSpan=$result2-num_rows;

echo "<tr>"
echo "<td rowspan=" . $rowSpan . ">" . $count++ . "</td>";
echo "<td rowspan=" . $rowSpan . ">".$deptname."</td>";
```

The second while loop must output

```
<td>$name</td></tr>
```

The important thing is to close the table row  inside the while loop also start a new table row in case you are printing a second name for the same dept.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $cmsDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$cmsDB->prefix("departments")."");

echo "<br /><br /><table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
<tr>
<th>Bil</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Staff</th>
</tr>";

$count =1 ;

while($row = $cmsDB->fetchArray($result))
{
$deptid=$row['deptid']; 
$deptname=$row['deptname']; 

 global $cmsDB;
$result2 = $cmsDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$cmsDB->prefix("staff")." WHERE deptid=$deptid");


$num_rows = $cmsDB->getRowsNum($result2);


$rowSpan=$num_rows;

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td rowspan=" . $rowSpan . ">" . $count++ . "</td>";
echo "<td rowspan=" . $rowSpan . ">".$deptname."</td>";

while($row = $cmsDB->fetchArray($result2))
{

$name=$row['name']; 
echo "<td>$name</td></tr>";
}

}


echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this logic and it worked perfectly. You can try this.

```
$result = get_pending_sales_order_details(ST_SALESORDER, $_POST['customer_id'],null);

$order_count=0;
$array_ord=array();


while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

 $result23 = get_pending_sales_order_details(ST_SALESORDER, $_POST['customer_id'],$myrow["order_no"]);

        $row_span = mysql_num_rows($result23);

        start_row();
        if($currentorg != $myrow["order_no"])

        {
        label_cell($myrow["order_no"], "rowspan='".$row_span."' align=center");
        }


    label_cell($myrow["stk_code"], "align=center");
    label_cell($myrow["description"], "align=left");
    label_cell($myrow["pending_quantity"], "align=center");

    end_row();
    $currentorg = $myrow["order_no"];
}
```